# Pre-set replies for Out of Office Assistant in Outlook

Tags: outlook, vsto

My company would like employees to have an option of choosing from pre-set messages for their out of office assistant instead of letting them type their own.

I can't see to figure out an easy way to accomplish this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this is possible (I would love to hear otherwise). You would simply need to provide each employee with the text they need to use, which they would paste into the OOO box. How they store that information is up to them -- depending on the Outlook version, you could create an OOO signature or a Quick Part.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a COM add-in and invoke your own form on a button click. That form can have any custom UI, and you can then manipulate the OOF rules programmatically.

Outlook Object Model does not provide a direct way to manipulate OOF settings. You can do that using either

1. Access the OOF template message (`"IPM.Note.Rules.OofTemplate.Microsoft"`) directly using `Folder.GetStorage` and get/set the `PR_STORE_OFFLINE` property (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6632000B"`) using `Store.PropertyAccessor`. You will not be able to set the HTML OOF template or have different replies for inside/outside senders, you need EWS for that.
2. Use EWS (see for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/hh532556(v=exchg.80).aspx)
3. Use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) and its [RDOOutOfOfficeAssistant](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOOutOfOfficeAssistant.htm)  object.

Comment: can you share more details about 1st solution

Comment: Take a look at the data with OutlookSpy - go to the Inbox folder, click IMAPIFolder button, go to the "Associated Contents" tab.

Comment: when check that folder i found 5 oof templates :(

Comment: Only one of them is linked to the OOF rule - look at the rules and see which one uses the template. Keep in mind that the latest versions of Outlook / Exchange do not even look at the rule - it is all done using EWS.